# What are the ramifications of duplicate variable definitions?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have code that looks like this:

```
var variableX:uint = something;    

if (variableX > 1)
{
  var variableY:uint = foo;
}
else
{
  var variableY:uint = bar;
}
```

When compiled in FlashDevelop, the compiler gives the following warning:

```
Warning: Duplicate variable definition.
```

Being a beginner with AS3 and programming I don't like compiler warnings. The compiler is looking at me through squinted eyes and saying "Ok, buddy, I'll let you off this time. But I'm warning you!" and then doesn't tell me what's so wrong about what I'm doing.

What should I be aware of when I do something like this? I mean I could obviously define the variable outside of `if` and then this wouldn't be a problem, but maybe there's something more to this? Or is the compiler just giving a helpful nudge saying "hey, you might have accidentally created two different variables with the same name" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct in your assessment of the warning.  It's just letting you know there was already a variable in scope with that name and that you're about to redefine it.  This way you don't accidentally overwrite a variable.  Although they may not appear to be in the same scope if you check out variable hoisting on this page you'll see what the deal is: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9d.html

> An interesting implication of the lack of block-level scope is that
>   you can read or write to a variable before it is declared, as long as
>   it is declared before the function ends. This is because of a
>   technique called hoisting , which means that the compiler moves all
>   variable declarations to the top of the function. For example, the
>   following code compiles even though the initial trace() function for
>   the num variable happens before the num variable is declared:

My personal tendency is to just bring the definition up top myself to avoid having extra warnings that make me miss more important issues.  Been out of AS3 for a while but in large projects people let things go and you end up with 100s-1000s of warnings and relevant ones get buried.